# Hide the version of a jar in a build having packaging type "ear"

Tags: maven-2

I work with **Maven2**.
I want to know is there a way to **hide** the **version** of the jar **after** the **build** with **packaging type** "**ear**".

For example if:

1. I use junit with version 5 i want to get it in my ear with the name junit.jar and not junit-5.jar.
2. I use an external jar named "file.jar" and i do build with type of packaging "ear" and i want that after the build this jar will added in the ear with his same original name "file.jar" and not "file-version.jar".

I'm not using plugin, i'm just dependency:
I have this pom for example:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>file</groupId>
        <artifactId>file</artifactId>
        <version>1</version> // just because it can't be empty
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I have installed the file.jar in my local repository by using mvn install:install-file

And I want to have as artifact an ear "project.ear" that contains the file.jar **without the version name** (not file-1.jar)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the name with the `<bundleFileName>` tag in your `<***Module>`.

But I must say, I don't really see the point of having a more obscure name for an jar.

---

**Resources :**

- [maven.apache.org - EAR Modules](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html)

Comment: I use an external jar named "file.jar" and i do build with type of packaging "ear" and i want that after the build, this jar will be added in the ear with his same original name "file.jar" and not "file-version.jar".

Answer (score 1):

Set the fileNameMapping property of the ear pluging:

```
<configuration>
  <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
</configuration>
```

this is not in the documentation, but should work.

edit:
i just have a look at the source of the plugin and this is only in availible in the latest snapshot version of the ear plugin (2.5-SNAPHOT)

Comment: And where can I found this version 2.5?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-testing-development-plugins.html